# GitHub is only uploading the ".idea" folder, why?

Tags: git, android-studio, github

if I click in my Android Studio Project on "VCS" -> "Import into version control" -> "Share project on GitHub" then it is only creating a repository with the .idea folder. Like this: https://github.com/Penta-Games/Mr.Politik

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI I removed the android and java tags as they are not applicable to this question, please review the descriptions of android and java tags before using them on a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all files are committed:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push
```

Comment: In which file do I have to write this code? I'm net to GitHub :)

Comment: @TheUseraccawd you execute this in the git console. You should have git installed on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to VCS -> Import into Version Control -> Share Project on GitHub. Enter Repository name, Description and click Share button.In the next window check all files inorder to add files for initial commit and click OK.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant "Share Project on GitHub". Look at my edited question.